# JQuery drag/drop: Only the first dropped item can be deleted

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a table of draggable rows, which can be drug into the droppable area and then disabled so the same row cannot be dropped again unless deleted from the droppable area.

This works fine for one item but does not work for deleting additional items from the dropped area. Only the first dragged item is deleted from the dropped area, when clicking delete on the other items, nothing happens. Also the dropped area keeps a position/placeholder for the dragged items, so when I drag a new item in the drop area, it is placed below where the last item was.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr class="bb">
            <th class="artcl_hdr text-center"></th>
            <th class="artcl_hdr text-center">Source</th>
            <th class="artcl_hdr text-center">Title</th>
            <th class="artcl_hdr text-center">Publish Date</th>
            <th class="artcl_hdr text-center">Share</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        if(is_array($bookmarks))
        {
                echo '<tr class="bmkitem" id="'.$bookmark['aid'].'">';
                echo '<td class="text-center bkgcol-white"><a href="#" title="Delete bookmark" id="bkm_delete"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg pomegranate" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>';
                echo '<td class="text-center"><span id="article_source" class="label '.$label.'">'.$bookmark['name'].'</span></td>';
                echo '<td class="bkm-title text-left"><a href="'.$bookmark['link'].'" target="_blank" id="bookmark-link">'.$bookmark['title'].'</a></td>';
                echo '<td class="key-title text-center">'.$formatted_date.'</td>';
                echo '<td class="artcl_info text-left"><div class="add-this addthis_native_toolbox" data-url="'.$bookmark['link'].'" data-title="'.$bookmark['title'].'"></div></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div class="panel-body text-left" id="bkm-dropbox">
<div class="text-center">
    <p class="temp-text">Drag Bookmarks Here</p>
</div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {

$(".bmkitem").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    containment: "document",
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: 'true',
    start: function(event, ui) {
        source = $(this).find('#article_source').text()
        contents = $(this).find('#bookmark-link').text();
    }
});

$('#bkm-dropbox').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'hover',
    acceptable: '.bmkitem',
    containment: 'document',

    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).find(".temp-text").remove();

        $(this).append('<span><a href="Javascript:void(0)"" id="drop_delete"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg pomegranate left_pad_push" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>' + source + ' - ' + contents + '</span><br />');

        ui.draggable.draggable("disable");
        selected_row = ui.draggable.find("i").hide();

        $('#drop_delete').on('click', function () {
            $(this).parent('span').remove();
            ui.draggable.draggable("enable");
            selected_row.show();
        });
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the dropped items with the same id again and again. The id of the element must be unique in html.

A common mistake with draggable/droppable that the cloned dropped part keeps the original ids. You need to remove or alter the dropped ids to not break dom selectors.

You may modify your code to create a "unique" id each time when you drop the item:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".bmkitem").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    containment: "document",
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: 'true',
    start: function(event, ui) {
        source = $(this).find('#article_source').text()
        contents = $(this).find('#bookmark-link').text();
    }
});

var id = 0;
$('#bkm-dropbox').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'hover',
    acceptable: '.bmkitem',
    containment: 'document',

    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).find(".temp-text").remove();

        id++;
        $(this).append('<span><a href="Javascript:void(0)"" id="drop_delete'+ id + '"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg pomegranate left_pad_push" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>' + source + ' - ' + contents + '</span><br />');

        ui.draggable.draggable("disable");
        selected_row = ui.draggable.find("i").hide();

        $('#drop_delete' + id ).on('click', function () {
            $(this).parent('span').remove();
            ui.draggable.draggable("enable");
            selected_row.show();
        });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks apr. That worked great. The only issue now is that new items added to dropped area start below where the last item was. So if the drop area is empty, the next item dropped is positioned below where the last item was deleted instead of at the top of the dropped area. Is there a way to clear the empty space/row in the dropped area when an item is deleted, so the any remaining items in the dropped area are shifted to the top of the drop area(div)?

Comment: Use your browser developer tools and check what remains in the target div after an item deleted.

Comment: Thanks apr. I followed your advice and I see that the break "<br>" is remaining in the drop area. I removed. Works now.